# aiokafka: One consumer for each partition

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

Imagine that messages in kafka topic are archive paths of MDB-files (MS Access) in OS (something like this: `path/to/folder/archive_name.zip`). Consumer takes that archive paths, unpacking them to temp file, then converts unpacked file to temp CSV, then loads to pandas dataframe and makes some processing. As you could guess that can take significant amount of time. Let's all these take 1 second to perform.

The aim is to process them fast.

As far as I can see this can be archieved if to route messages to **several partitions** and to handle them with **the same amount** of consumers.

Here what I'm doing now with aiokafka:

```
import asyncio

import aiokafka


async def consume(consumer: aiokafka.AIOKafkaConsumer):
    consumer.subscribe(['topic_name'])
    async for msg in consumer:
        # processing
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    consumer = aiokafka.AIOKafkaConsumer(
        bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
        group_id='MY_GROUP_ID',
    )
    await consumer.start()
    try:
        coros = []
        for _ in consumer.partitions_for_topic('topic_name'):  # f.e. 4 partitions 
            coros.append(consume(consumer))
        await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    finally:
        await consumer.stop()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Well it seems that it works. But maybe there is already realized solutions for this kind of tasks?

P.S. Creating additional k8s-pods can help. Here we do not need asyncio. Just specify the consumer group.

Comment: Your solution is valid, this is how kafka is working, the question should be is to investigate the bottleneck of your process,  which comes to "writing the converted file back to disk" ,  or "the power of your machine" , if scaling to different machines/pods gives you better throughput that make sense, in the end your writing to same disk storage, do you get to 100% running on the same machine/pod parallel process?

Comment: Your use case does not have any ordering semantics or limitations,  you might as well define 1000 partitions

Comment: @RanLupovich, well, that was a toy example. Thanks for your answer